# Selenium - how to select option from option list? (where only partial text is known?)

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, automated-tests

Select option item that partially match string (if this is not possible I will need to get the fullname of listed option items into the program so it can be selected)

```
Example if you want to select optionTQW 4493, you can just select with TQW?

<select id="_myselector" name="select-list">
<option value='1'>OptionZ 2345</option>
<option value='2'>optionTQW 4493</option>             
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>id=_myselector</td>
    <td>label=glob:option* 4493</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an XPath selector:
    //select[@id='_myselector']/option[contains(., 'TQW')]

For a more specific answer, it may be helpful to know if you are using the selenium scripting language with Selenium IDE or a certain language wrapper (Java, python, ruby, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Use xpath selector `"//select[@id='_myselector']/option[contains(text(),'TQW')]"`

Answer (score 0):

This is in ruby selenium webdriver-

```
@driver.find_element(:id, "_myselector").find_element(:css,"option[value='1']").click
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the built in `SelectElement` class in the Selenium.Support.UI Namspace

Here is an extension method I created to help with this.

```
public static void SelectOptionFromDropdown(this IWebDriver driver,IWebElement dropdown, SelectBy selectBy, string item)
    {
        switch (selectBy)
        {
            case SelectBy.Index:
                int index;
                if (Int32.TryParse(item, out index))
                {
                    new SelectElement(dropdown).SelectByIndex(index);
                }
                else
                {
                    ExceptionHandler.LogException("Unable to Convert String To Int", "WebdriverExtension", "SelectOptionFromDropdown");
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                break;

            case SelectBy.Text:
                new SelectElement(dropdown).SelectByText(item);
                break;
            case SelectBy.Value:
                new SelectElement(dropdown).SelectByValue(item);
                break;
        }
    }
```

I just reread your post and you wanted to select on a partial string match, I don't know how to do this and prefer to use more rigorous methods. So I tend to use Index or Value.

But hope this helps point you in the right direction.